# Memory leak in a recursive function in c

Tags: c, memory-leaks, tree

I need some help with memory leak in my C program. The following function searches a radix trie to find a word with a given number. It allocates some memory in every recursive call and I don't know how to sort it out so that the blocks allocated aren't lost. Please help.

```
char *substring(char *str, int position, int length) {
  int c = 0;
  char *sub = malloc(length*(sizeof(char))+1); 
  while (c < length) {
    sub[c] = str[position + c];
    c++;
  }
  return sub;
}

void prev(int w, int start, int end) {
  char *newWord = "";
  bool found = false;

  void prevRec(struct tNode *t, 
  int w, int start, int end, char *soFar, int prevLength) {
  if (t != NULL) {
    char *updatedWord = malloc(strlen(soFar) + strlen(t->word));
    strcpy(updatedWord,soFar);
    strcat(updatedWord,t->word);
    printf("%s\n", updatedWord);
    int length = strlen(t->word);
    if (t->count == w) {
      found = true;
      if ((start > -1) && (end <= strlen(updatedWord))) { 
        newWord = updatedWord;

      } else {
        newWord = "";
      }
    } else {
      struct tNode *tmp = t->child;
      struct tNode *tmp1 = NULL;
      while ((tmp != NULL) && (!found)) {
        prevRec(tmp,w,start,end,updatedWord,length);
        tmp1 = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->brother;
        updatedWord = substring(updatedWord, 0, strlen(updatedWord) - prevLength);
      }
    } 
  }
}
  prevRec(root,w,start,end,newWord,0);
  printf("%s\n",newWord);
  if (strlen(newWord) == 0) printf("ignored");
  else {
    char *tmp = substring(newWord,start,end - start + 1);
    insert(tmp);
    free(tmp);
  }
```

Comment: did you run it thr' [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: `char *updatedWord = malloc(strlen(soFar) + strlen(t->word));` should be `char *updatedWord = malloc(sizeof(*updatedWord) * (strlen(soFar) + strlen(t->word) + 1));`.  
`strcpy` won't copy `\0` and is generally not secure. maybe you should use `strncpy`.  
You should also format your code a little better, the closing `}` are not so readable...  
As for your problem, general rule is "when you don't need it, delete it", in the uppermost function that made it being alloc'd

Comment: I tried to free the memory once the updatedWord is used, but segmentation errors keep appearing. I don't know where exactly and which pointer I should deallocate.

Comment: @Eregrith Of course `strcpy()` will copy `'\0'`, but only once.

Comment: @unwind ah I forgot about that. Thanks. So does `strcat` then, I presume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must free what you've allocated. In your case you could to sth. like that: replace

```
updatedWord = substring(updatedWord, 0, strlen(updatedWord) - prevLength);
```

by

```
char *sub = substring(updatedWord, 0, strlen(updatedWord) - prevLength);
free( updatedWord );
updatedWord = sub;
```

and add another

```
free( updatedWord );
```

as last line of your `if( t != NULL )` block.

Besides as @Eregith has already mentioned in his comment, the '+1' for NULL is missing in the length you are allocating. And you should also add some error checking, as `malloc()` may return `NULL`